# dataentry form , how to define subform in main form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I want to create a form for dataentry in access.  I Have these tables. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqLu5.jpg)

I have a personaldetail table, which includes information about student first name, last name, etc.
I have information about technical skills which has different groups (6 groups) programming, languages,banking, etc.

Each group has different parts: for example, Programming has 4 parts JAVA, PHP, C, Python.
Languages also have different parts English, German, Spanish, French

Banking has these parts: Risk Management, Project Management

Each student has different skills; first student knows Java, php, German, Project ManagementI have these tables.

I have main form for personal details how should I define subform which allows to enter data about skills.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what the issue is. Main form bound to PersonalDetails and Subform bound to [student skill] with a combobox to select skill. Basic Access functionality. Perhaps you need cascading (dependent) comboboxes. Select group in combobox 1 and this causes combobox 2 list to filter to only those skills associated with that group. Common requirement, however, doesn't work nicely in a continuous or datasheet form if the combobox list displays lookup alias.